# Why does my quicksort program crash?

Tags: c++, quicksort

Given below is the code that I could think of for the quicksort technique. I'm not sure if its correct but as per my logic I guess it should work fine. However, I think I have overdone it too much because when I try to run this code on DevC++, it crashes and closes the program. It does not happen with every program so there is obviously some problem with this code only.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

int quick(int, int);

int split(int beg, int end);

int a[7] = { 43, 6, 235, 76, 23, 65, 29 };

int main() {
    quick(0, 6);
    getch();
    return 1;
}

int quick(int beg, int end) {
    //trial for self coding

    int loc = split(beg, end);
    quick(beg, loc - 1);//first half
    quick(loc + 1, end);//second half

    //end of coding

    cout << "\nThe sorted array is :\t";
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        cout << a[i] << "\t";
    return 0;
}

//SPLIT FUNC STARTS
int split(int beg, int end) {
    int temp, loc, left, right, count = 1;
    left = beg;
    right = end;
    loc = beg;
    while (left != right) {
        if ((count % 2) != 0) {
            while (a[loc] <= a[right]) {
                right--;
            }
            if (loc == right)
                return loc;
            if (a[loc] > a[right]) {
                temp = a[loc];
                a[loc] = a[right];
                a[right] = temp;
                loc = right;
                left++;
                count++;
                continue;
            }
        }// end of count%2 if
        else {
            while (a[left] <= a[loc])
                left++;
            if (loc == left)
                return loc;
            if (a[loc] < a[left]) {
                temp = a[loc];
                a[loc] = a[right];
                a[right] = temp;
                loc = left;
                right--;
                count++;
                continue;
            }
        }//end of else
    }// end of while
    return loc;
}
```

Comment: Screaming URGENT!! at us is not going to help matters my friend.

Comment: Urgent? When is the homework due?

Comment: `If you have something urgent, your time would be better spent asking the people around you, or figuring it out for yourself` quoting http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6506/an-urgent-tag-for-questions-that-need-answers-within-minutes#answer-6513

Comment: @DavidTitarenco, {tag:homework} is on the way out and such kind of questions might get closed in near future (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/trogdor-ate-my-homework-tag)

Comment: What does your program say when it crashes? If you could run it in a debugger to find out which line it crashes on it would help. If you can't use a debugger, then adding print statements would help.

Comment: Also, if you urgently need a sorting function, then you should either [use `std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) or start your homework sooner.

Comment: 1. Replace DevC++ by a modern compiler. It is really old and full of bugs. 2. Use a debugger. 3. Look at every loop, mostly "crashes" happen because of Segmentation faults which are usually read/write access to arrays which are not big enough.

Comment: You should use `#include <iostream>` instead of `#include <iostream.h>` per the C++ standard.  This will require you to add `using namespace std;` or `using namespace std::bout;` (and one for each other object) or qualify your objects in code like `std::cout`.

Answer (score 3):

Compile the program with debug flags and run it in a debugger.  Most IDEs offer a "Debug" button.  GCC would allow you to compile debug flags with the -g option and you can use gdb.

In this case, I did the latter with `g++ -g quicksort.cpp && gdb a.out`.  Once iside, I used `run`.  This immediately gave me a "Could not access memory." error complete with line number.  `print <variable>` will print variables and `quit` will exit.

I am specifically not giving the actual error location information for educational purposes.

Answer (score 3):

#### Compile Errors

I put this in a file and compiled with:

```
g++ -g yourcode.cpp
```

First problem:

```
yourcode.cpp:1:21: fatal error: iostream.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Followed by:

```
yourcode.cpp: In function ‘int quick(int, int)’:
yourcode.cpp:23:5: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
yourcode.cpp:23:5: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/iostream:62:18: note:   ‘std::cout’
```

Instead of `#include <iostream.h>`, you should have `#include <iostream>`. You also need `using namespace std;` It's possible your compiler is incredibly out of date. Most compilers are free, so I'd highly recommend getting one that won't let you make mistakes like this while you're learning. I haven't used Windows in a while, but presumably **Eclipse** works about the same on it, plus **Visual Studio Express** is free too. I think **Qt Creator** also works on Windows. Pick any of them, just *stop using the one you're on now*.

I also removed your weird DOS input function that you're calling to pause the program. Use `std::cin` if you want input.

#### Segmentation Fault

Now if I run it, I get:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

So that's fun, what does gdb say?

```
Starting program: /home/brendan/a.out 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004008b7 in split (beg=0, end=6) at yourcode.cpp:55
55              while (a[left] <= a[loc])
```

Which indicates that at some point, on line 55, `a[left]` or `a[loc]` are not valid locations in memory. You probably need to add some sort of code to make sure `left` and `loc` stay within the bounds of the array.

If you **urgently** need to know what's causing your program to crash, **running this process yourself will be much faster than asking someone else to do it for you**. This process is **easy**, and as a result, very few people will be willing to run it for you. I only did as an example, because I realize it's not obvious when you first start programming.

Note: I used command-line programs to check this because it's fast, but you may be more comfortable using the debugger in an IDE. If you run Eclipse, you should be able to just click the "debug" button (usually a green bug) and it will tell you this exact information.

Comment: I specifically omitted the answer to encourage actually doing it.

Comment: @JonathanSeng When I was learning to program, I was constantly frustrated by how few examples I could find of things, so I tried to make this complete enough to see the actual debugging process that I use. The actual result isn't really that important, since it's just the first step. Fixing the problem and then verifying it is much harder (and should involve doing this process several times).

Comment: And I was frustrated by how many people refused to learn how to debug while relying on other people in the computer lab to do gdb and the like for them.

Comment: @JonathanSeng I added a bit at the end to discuss this a little bit. For someone who *wants* to be good at programming, this could be very helpful. I know **I** wish someone had taught me to use gdb and valgrind earlier. As for people who *don't** want to put in work.. who cares? In my experience, you can't change people who don't want to charge, so I say ignore them. They're only hurting themselves.

Comment: Yes, but you set a bad example for those who read this post later.